# How to make another ImageButton appear when hovering over ImageButton

Tags: libgdx, imagebutton

How can i make so that if i hover over a imagebutton another imagebutton appears over that imagebutton and when you move your mouse outside it returns back to the first imagebutton? I have tried a lot of combinations but nothing so far.

So far i have tried

```
ImageButton(Drawable imageUp,
                Drawable imageDown,
                   Drawable imageChecked)
```

but the setChecked(boolean isChecked) hasn't worked for this method and when using focusListener it turns the ImageButton into another ImageButton when you hover over it but it doesn't return to its first stage when you go outside the ImageButton. Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `imageDown` use `imageOver`.

According to my understanding:

- imageUp
  default button
- imageOver
  when the mouse/focus is over the button
- imageDown
  when the button is pressed (the mouse is clicked)
- imageChecked
  when the button has the status `checked`
- imageCheckedOver
  when the button has the status `checked` and the mouse/focus is over the button
- imageDisabled
  when the button has the status `disabled`

You can use the ImageButtonStyle for this. Pass it to the consructor of your button or use the appropriate setter.

```
ImageButtonStylestyle = new ImageButtonStyle();
style.imageUp = imageUp;
style.imageOver = imageDown;
style.imageChecked = imageChecked;
```

Ps.:
I assumed you do not really want to change the button, just the displayed image.

Comment: I have tried style.imageOver but it doesn't give the desired effect when hovering over the imagebutton. And wich is the best method to use for the hover when we add the listener to the button, i asume it would be FocusListener?

Comment: And another strange thing is that when i click on the imagebutton it still turns into the other imagebutton despite there being no imageDown in ImageButtonStyle.

Comment: Nevermind yust found the solution, i forgot to add stage.act() in the render method